# ssrs 2016 auto refreshing of kpi

Tags: reporting-services, kpi

I have created couple of KPIs on SSRS 2016. They both get data from a table using a simple select query:

```
SELECT 
       SUM(Income) Income,
       Count(Contracts) Contracts
FROM table
```

On dataset Properties > Caching, I have set a cache refresh plan to run every 5 minutes. The refresh occurs as scheduled, however it doesn't update my KPIs unless I hit the refresh bottom of browser to reload report server site. Then, I can see the figures has been changed (if any). (e.g if I had 8520 contracts before, after refreshing, I have 8522, it means two new contracts has been added into database)

Is there a way to auto-refresh the KPI itself? I mean to see changes in every 5 minutes as scheduled for dataset, so I don't have to refresh my browser.

Answer (score 1):

If the report is a paginated report, then you can set the AutoRefresh property of the report to something greater than 0; the value is in seconds. You do this in Report Designer (SSDT), or Report Builder. AutoRefresh is a Report level property; you can find it in the Properties pane.

If the report is one of the new Mobile reports supported by SSRS 2016, there is no auto refresh option.

Comment: I seem to be having this problem, even with the setting applied to 5 mins, the report does not reload itself. Any help with this is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in Cummulative Update for SQL Server 2016 SP1. It was released on 1/18/2017.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2016-sp1/